# Buildroot build failed for STM32MP157d-dk1 board

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot

I have been trying to build a `buildroot` image for stm32MP157d-dk1 board. I followed [Intro to Embedded Linux Part 1 - Buildroot](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/intro-to-embedded-linux-part-1-buildroot/a73a56de62444610a2187cd9e681c3f2) and [STM32MP1 Buildroot external tree](https://github.com/bootlin/buildroot-external-st).

During the make process I countered the following errors, the build unable to locate `arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`. Below is a snip from the error log.

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: /home/user/Projects/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc 
Build flags: -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE;-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE;-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64;-Os;-g0;-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Id flags:  

The output was:
2
/home/user/Projects/buildroot/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: No such file or directory
```

The guidelines provide by [Intro to Embedded Linux Part 1 - Buildroot](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/intro-to-embedded-linux-part-1-buildroot/a73a56de62444610a2187cd9e681c3f2) uses the following command set.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -y git build-essential libncurses5-dev
Next, we need to clone the Buildroot repository:
cd ~
mkdir Projects
cd Projects
git clone git://git.buildroot.net/buildroot
cd buildroot
make stm32mp157a_dk1_defconfig
make menuconfig
make
```

The above instruction set uses `stm32mp157a_dk1_defconfig` with is for a 650MHz clock speed. Although the image works I would like to run the device at 800 MHz, which is the clock speed for `stm32mp157d_dk1`

From [STM32MP1 Buildroot external tree](https://github.com/bootlin/buildroot-external-st) I followed the following command set. Since I area had `buildroot` downloaded and configured I skipped the first command in the following command list.

```
$ git clone -b st/2022.02.7 https://github.com/bootlin/buildroot.git
$ git clone -b st/2022.02.7 https://github.com/bootlin/buildroot-external-st.git
$ cd buildroot/
buildroot/ $ make BR2_EXTERNAL=../buildroot-external-st st_stm32mp157c_dk2_defconfig
buildroot/ $ make
```

Following is the content in `/buildroot/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin`

[image: buildroot-external-toolchain-bin]

The 'arm-buildroot-*`can be found in`buildroot/output/host/bin`

[image: buildroot-output-host-bin]

Note: instead of `st_stm32mp157c_dk2_defconfig` I used `st_stm32mp157d_dk1_defconfig`

It appears that the build process is looking for `arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` in a different location.

Any thoughts how to address this issue? I am happy to provide additional information

Comment: Try doing a `make clean`